# Disproving existence of real root in some interval for a quintic equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Disprove the statement: There is a real root of equation $\frac{1}{5}x^5+\frac{2}{3}x^3+2x=0$ on the interval (1,2).

I am not sure whether to prove by counter-example or by assuming the statement is true and then proving by contradiction.

Comment: It looks as though there is at least one very obvious root ...

Comment: What could a counter-example for non-existence be? You'd need to try all reals, you won't have enough time for that...
Also: $x=0$ is a trivial real root so something is fishy with the assignment.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that the I am supposed to disprove the statement on the interval (1,2).

Comment: The thing is positive there. There is also no real root between $17$ and $77$. One line, no machinery.

Comment: $f(x) > f(1)$ for $x \in (1,2)$ where $f(x)$ is the polynomial you're looking at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step: what is the value of the polynomial for $x=1$?

Second step: what is the sign of the derivative of this polynomial on the interval $[1,2]$?

Third step: conclusion.

**edit**

Altenative: $x\ge 1$, therefore $x^n\ge 1$ for all $n\ge 1$. Hence $$\frac{1}{5}x^5+\frac{2}{3}x^3+2x\ge \frac{1}{5} +\frac{2}{3} +2 $$
whenever $x\ge 1$.

Comment: I don't think I am supposed to use calculus for this proof.

Comment: @user3699546 See edit.

Comment: In my opinion you should, instead.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense to me now.

Comment: Derivative isn't sufficient here - you'd need to check every derivative up to the fifth to show that the function stays positive.  However, the observation that every part of the function is a simple function known to be positive in the given range works.

Comment: @Brilliand how comes? If $f'(x)>0$ for $x\ge x_0$, then $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$ for $x \ge x_0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Proving that the derivative is positive for all x∈(1,2) is about equal in difficulty (and kind) to solving the original question, so I don't see how that gains anything.  My previous comment was about taking the derivative only at a specific point... which I think is the only reasonable way to go about solving this with derivatives.

Comment: @Brilliand the derivative is $x^4 + 2x^2 + 2$. Set $t=x^2$ and it's a quadratic equation, it is not difficult to see when it is positive and when negative.

Comment: @Ant Well, that does result in solving the assignment... I still think "find the derivative and solve that" was a useless hint, but I guess it's subjective.

Comment: @Brilliand well I agree that is much more difficult than it needs to be, but it works! (Especially given that we are talking about the sum of three strictly positive terms ! :-) )

Answer (score 3):

All terms are increasing on $\Bbb R$, so the sum is also increasing. There is the trivial root $0$, hence it's the only root.

---

Alternately, you can factor out $x$, then you are left with a biquadratic equation $\frac15x^4+\frac23x^2+2=0$, then let $x^2=y$, and you have a trinomial to solve. But you don't even have to: it's obviously always positive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x$ can't be a root on the interval, as it is positive throughout, so you can divide through by $x$ and solve the resulting quadratic in $x^2$

Answer (score 0):

Odd-degree polynom with real coefficients always has at least one real root, as all complex roots of such polynom are conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It's sufficient to show that:

1. f(1) > 0
2. For all n > 0: f(1 + n) > f(1)

Step #2 means that the function is increasing at all points to the right of x=1.  From this you can say that f(x) doesn't equal zero (has a real root) in the range (1,2) because f(x) is always above 1 in that range.

Working out the algebra:

```
f(1 + n) = (1/5 + 2/3 + 2) + 4n + 4n^2 + (2 + 2/3)n^3 + n^4 + (1/5)n^5
```

Then to show that f(1 + n) > f(1), you have to show:

```
(1/5 + 2/3 + 2) + 4n + 4n^2 + (2 + 2/3)n^3 + n^4 + (1/5)n^5 > (1/5 + 2/3 + 2)
```

Canceling the (1/5 + 2/3 + 2) gives:

```
4n + 4n^2 + (2 + 2/3)n^3 + n^4 + (1/5)n^5 > 0
```

It should be easy to see that as n increases, this inequality remains true, as long as n > 1.

Edit: here's one way to work this out:

Divide: by 4: `n + n^2 + (3/4)n^3 + (1/4)n^4 + (1/20)n^5 > 0`

We know that n>1 so we can add a second inequality which removes the initial `n +`:

```
n + n^2 + (3/4)n^3 + (1/4)n^4 + (1/20)n^5 > n^2 + (3/4)n^3 + (1/4)n^4 + (1/20)n^5 > 0
```

Subtract out the middle pieces to make the middle zero:

```
n > 0 > -n^2 - (3/4)n^3 - (1/4)n^4 - (1/20)n^5
```

Answer (score 0):

Factor $x ( 1/5 x^4 + 2/3 x^2 + 2 )$.  So one root is $x=0$.

Let $z = x^2$, then we have $1/5 z^2 + 2/3 z + 2 = 0$.  The discriminant<sup>1</sup> is $(4/9-8/5)$, which is negative, so there are no real roots in $z$.  A real root in $x$ implies a real root in $z$, so $x = 0$ is the only real root in $x$.

---

<sup>1</sup>  The term $(b^2 - 4 ac)$ within the square root portion of the quadratic equation.